# step form validator on input with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a multi step form, generated with php and sql database.

All my input, have different names, which can change with queries.
And I can have more than one input with the same type on a step. I'd like to validate each input, select, and checkbox for each step when I click to next.

here is my html code for the first step :

```
<fieldset>
 <h2 class="fs-title">Title</h2>
 <label>01) question 1</label><br>
 <input type="text" value="" required="required" name="REP_01"><br>
 <label>02) question 2</label><br>
 <input type="text" value="" required="required" name="REP_02"><br>
 <label>03) question 3</label><br>
 <input type="number" value="" name="REP_03" required="required"><br>
 <label>04)question 4</label><br>
 <input type="number" value="" name="REP_04" required="required"><br>
 <input type="button" value="Suivant" class="next action-button" name="next">
 </fieldset>
```

here is my jquery script to try to validate it :

```
$(".next").click(function(){
  var erros = 0;
  if (fieldsetn == 1) {

     if ($('input[type="text"]').val().length === 0) {
        $('input[type="text"]').addClass('warning');
        $('input[type="text"]').attr("placeholder","Missing value"); 
       erros = 1;}
     else {
       $('input[type="text"]').removeClass('warning');}
  }
```

This script works for the first input type text of my step, but not for the second.
I guess I have to put somewhere something like for each but for Jquery.

Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: If you're working with php and doing lot's of modeling and validations, I would suggest something like PHPActiveRecord. That solved my validations and modeling problems.   http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Validations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$(".next").click(function () {
    var erros = 0;
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
            $(this).addClass('warning');
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "Missing value");
            erros = 1;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('warning');
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dntu0co/

Comment: your code is 99.9% good.

When I put your code, the control is ok, but when I click on next, I can't go to the next step.

check the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2dntu0co/2/

Comment: I don't thinks it is related to the question you asked. this answer is the solution for your question and your link has much more issues. even it has more runtime errors. so please accept the answer and ask it as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select nth-element, than you can use `.eq(8)` (0 based). To loop every element, use `$.each`:

```
$('input[name="text"]').removeClass('warning');

$.each($('input[type="text"]'), function(){
   var currentElementInDom = $(this);
   if (currentElementInDom.val().length == 0) {
      /* rest of code */
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 var flag=false;
   $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
         if($(this).val()==''){
            flag=true;
            break;
          }
   });

  if (flag) {
        $('input[type="text"]').addClass('warning');
        $('input[type="text"]').attr("placeholder","Missing value"); 
       erros = 1;
   }else {
       $('input[name="text"]').removeClass('warning');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because using `val()` on a *set* of elements only returns the value of the *first* element.
Thus, if your first field is empty, all the others will have a "warning" class.

You could two different ways :

As you suggested, there is an [each    method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery, so you could do :

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
   if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
      $(this).addClass('warning');
      $(this).attr("placeholder","Missing value"); 
      erros = 1;
   }else {
       $(this).removeClass('warning');
   }
});
```

Or you could use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and do something like :

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter(function(){
   return $(this).val === '';
}).addClass('warning').attr("placeholder","Missing value");
```